# Forward request to multiple target servers on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

During the migration from an old version of a certain software to a new version both instances should receive the same SOAP requests. This should look like this:

```
 Enterprise Service Bus
          |
      (Request 1)
          |
        ?????
        /   \
       /     \
      /       \
     /         \
(Request 1) (Request 1)
   /             \
  /               \
Old               New
```

Is it possible to forward requests to multiple targets simultaneously with some AWS service like *Elastic Load Balancer* (ELB)?

Answer (score 1):

This traffic mirroring on aws tutorial might be useful, there is a section dedicated to load balancer considerations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-how-it-works.html